# Why do I hear no sound when playing midi with mido on macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, midi, mido

I can play and hear midi files on macOS with:

```
timidity song.mid
```

So I suppose my midi driver is working.

However, I can't hear any sound when playing with `mido`. Here's my code:

```py
import mido

def play(path: str):
    file = mido.MidiFile(path)
    with mido.open_output() as port:
        for message in file.play():
            port.send(message)

def list_devices():
    print(mido.get_output_names())
    # ['IAC Driver Bus 1', 'IAC Driver Bus 1'] if on macOS.
    # ['Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth 0'] if on Windows.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play('song.mid')
    # list_devices()
```

On macOS, it seems to be running, just inaudible. There is no error message.

On Windows, the same code runs perfectly and I can hear the music.

I wonder why `mido` can't play on macOS. Does anyone have an idea how to make it work on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike *Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth*, *IAC Driver Bus* is not a synth.
It is a *Bus* that has to be connected with some software synth.